# jQuery delay function with dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, delay, drop-down-menu

```
<ul id="mainNav">
  <li> <a href="#" class="greenTheme">MainNav</a>
    <ul class="subNav gTheme">
      <li class="first"><a href="#">SubNav1</a><span></span></li>
      <li><a href="#">SubNav2</a><span></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am developing a dropdown menu with jQuery hover function. I need to put delay on the hide function. I am using the following piece of code.

```
//Show/Hide
$('#mainNav > li').each(function(e){
$(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.subNav').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('ul.subNav').delay(100000).hide();     
    });
});
```

I used the delay function here but it is not working as expected. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll be the first to mention [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can add hide to the animation queue by adding a duration. As mentioned above without any duration it will not become a part of the queue or "stack". Check out this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkprogramming/hyEC5/#base

```
//Show/Hide
$('#mainNav > li').each(function(e){
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.subNav').show(); //fadeIn();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('ul.subNav').delay(1000).hide(1);    //fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Since you're using jQuery i'd use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` for a much more professional effect.

Answer (score 0):

To add `show` or `hide` to the jQuery animation queue you have to use an animation duration (eg 1ms)

```
$(this).find('ul.subNav').delay(100000).hide(1);
```

http://api.jquery.com/show/

> When a duration is provided, .show() becomes an animation method. The .show() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you could use HoverIntent for that, it would be much better.
Sample: http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/creating-delayed-drop-down-menus-in-jquery-without-losing-accessibility